# R: combined/ nested if_else statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here.
Trying to use a combined if_else statement in R::dplyr based on the values of two columns.
Code below doesn't work - only gives X+90?

Link to csv: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmyiwdazsvs7wko/VideoTrack_ed.csv?dl=0

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

VidTrack <- read_csv("VideoTrack_ed.csv")

x <- VidTrack$course

Perp <- if_else(("R" %in% VidTrack$Side & VidTrack$course<270), x+90, x-270,
                if_else(("L" %in% VidTrack$Side & VidTrack$course<90), x+270,
                        x-90))
Perp_df <- as.data.frame(Perp)
```

In Excel this would be; `=IF(AND(H2="R",Z2<270),Z2+90,IF(AND(H2="R",Z2>=270),Z2+270,IF(AND(H2="L",Z2<90),Z2+270,Z2-90)))`

```
Column H = VidTrack$Side
Column Z = VidTrack$course
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when` listing all the conditions to be executed sequentially.

```
library(dplyr)

VidTrack %>%
   mutate(new_column = case_when(
                       Side == "R" & course < 270 ~ course + 90, 
                       Side == "R" & course >= 270  ~ course - 270, 
                       Side == "L" & course < 270 ~ course + 270, 
                       Side == "L" & course >= 90 ~ course - 90))
```

Comment: That solution creates two columns with values regardless of whether Side == R or Side == L. How can this be made into just one column. Thanks

Comment: @Jock Can you explain in words what you are trying to do? Because I don't understand excel syntax and I am confused about your R code. The syntax for `if_else` is `if_else(condition, true, false)` . I think first `condition` is `Side == "R" & course<270` and when it is true do `course+90` or else `course-270`. Can you clarify?

Comment: No problem. I need nested if_else statements. If `Side == "R" & course < 270` then value in new column is `course + 90`. If `Side == "R" & course >= 270`, then new column value is `course-270`, If `Side == "L" & course <90` then new column value is `course + 270`, If `Side == "L" & course >= 90`, then new column value is `course-90`. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Jock Thank you for the explanation. I have updated the answer, please have a look now and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: dplyr::case_when was exactaly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to open the file, so can't help much. But, shouldn't it be like this:

```
Perp <- if_else((VidTrack$Side == "R" & VidTrack$course < 270), x+90, x-270,
                if_else((VidTrack$Side == "L" & VidTrack$course < 90), x+270,
                        x-90))
```

Comment: Returns error: Error: `true` must be length 21537 (length of `condition`) or one, not 9522
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Sorry unable to check as I do not have data